# Amazon Textract: How to select 'Raw text' option

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, amazon-textract

We are trying integrate amazon Textract api in our node.js application. we are facing some issue, FeatureType parameter while processing image. we need to achieve the below option via api:

[image]

We are not finding the option in the AWS JavaScript SDK.

> export type FeatureType = "TABLES"|"FORMS"|string;

I'm trying this code:

```
const params = {
            Document: {
                /* required */
                Bytes: Buffer.from(fileData)
            },
            FeatureTypes: [""] // here i'm facing issue, if i pass "TABLES"|"FORMS" it working
        };
        var textract = new AWS.Textract({
            region: awsConfig.awsRegion,
            accessKeyId: awsConfig.awsAccesskeyID,
            secretAccessKey: awsConfig.awsSecretAccessKey
        })
        textract.analyzeDocument(params, (err, data) => {
            console.log(err, data)
            if (err) {
                return resolve(err)
            } else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
```

Getting this error:

```
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.FeatureTypes[0] to be a string
```

If I pass "TABLES"|"FORMS" its working but I need Raw Text option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried simply using `FeatureTypes: []`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Getting this error "InvalidParameterException: Request has invalid parameters"

Answer (score 1):

You have been calling the `analyzeDocument()` function:

> Analyzes an input document for relationships between detected items.

It returns various types of text:

```
'BlockType': 'KEY_VALUE_SET'|'PAGE'|'LINE'|'WORD'|'TABLE'|'CELL'|'SELECTION_ELEMENT',
```

The `LINE` and `WORD` blocks seem to match your requirements.

Alternatively, there is also a `detectDocumentText()` function:

> Detects text in the input document. Amazon Textract can detect lines of text and the words that make up a line of text.